# How to SELECT and ignore whitespace or blank strings?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to `SELECT DISTINCT` on a table to return a string.

If the string is blank, I don't want to know about that row.

To make matters worse, some users ahve been inputting whitespace and I want to ignore those rows too.

(How) can I do this? Thanks (MySql)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT col_name 
FROM table_name
WHERE TRIM(col_name) != ''
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`COALESCE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) in MySQL to get the first non-`NULL` column.

Additionally, you can also make use of [`CASE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html) statements to check if either column is `NULL` or an empty string and have a conditional query based off that.